# Pie Chart: load image in segment and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, click, chart.js

I have been trying to create a pie chart. I saw there were many different libraries and I have tried Chart.js since it seems to be one of the preferred ones. I am not determined to keep using this library so I am open to any other solution to my problem.

I have two main problems:

1. Loading an image to a section.
2. Making the segments clickable so that a div appears according to the selected section.

This is my **HTML**

```
<body>
  <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

This is my **JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ctx = $("#mycanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");

        var data = [
            {
                value: 51,
                color: "cornflowerblue",
                highlight: "lightskyblue",
                label: "Corn Flower Blue"           
            },
            {
                value: 51,
                color: "lightgreen",
                highlight: "yellowgreen",
                label: "Lightgreen"
            },
            {
                value: 51,
                color: "orange",
                highlight: "darkorange",
                label: "Orange"
            },
            {
                value: 51,
                color: "beige",
                highlight: "bisque",
                label: "Beige"
            },
            {
                value: 51,
                color: "aliceblue",
                highlight: "cadetblue",
                label: "AliceBlue"
            },
            {
                value: 51,
                color: "brown",
                highlight: "chocolate",
                label: "Brown"
            },
            {
                value: 51,
                color: "darkviolet",
                highlight: "deeppink",
                label: "DarkViolet"
            }
        ];

        var piechart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);

    });
</script>
```

Is there any way I can just give a backgroundImage to each segment? Like going through each one of them and adding the attribute while also assigning a click event?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to commercial charting libraries, you may consider [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com). It can load images into section labels and the labels can be put on the sections. It can also use images as a "wallpaper" to fill the sections. The sections can also be responded to mouse events (such as mouse clicked). Some example images are:

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

ChartDirector runs on the server side and supports multiple programming languages. For your reference, the code for the above charts in the ASP.NET framework in C#/VB are at:

[VB / C# Icon Pie Chart](http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnet.htm#iconpie.htm)

[VB / C# Texture Donut Chart](http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnet.htm#texturedonut.htm)

Comment: Thank you! I can't use a commercial charting library unfortunately, but it's good to know there's something like that, I will probably use it in the future. I decided to make it in Photoshop and use an image map on it. It was the fastest and easiest solution I could find, although now I need to find a way to make the image map responsive while using Foundation.